# How to change the flags of g++ called by libtool during a make

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, libtool, compiler-flags

I am trying to install vowpal_wabbit (https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit). I'm on windows 7 so I use cygwin64.

When calling "make", g++ is called:

```
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/include -I/include -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x ...
```

At the end I get the error:

```
comp_io.h:28:34: error: 'fileno' was not declared in this scope
        fil = gzdopen(fileno(stdin), "rb");                                      
global_data.cc: In constructor 'vw::vw()':
global_data.cc:316:32: error: 'fileno' was not declared in this scope
   stdout_fileno = fileno(stdout);
                                ^
Makefile:619: recipe for target 'global_data.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [global_data.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Sachou/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit'
Makefile:390: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Sachou/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit'
Makefile:502: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

From my research, I think calling g++ with the std=gnu++0x flag instead of std=c++0x may solve the problem.

I modified the makefile to read `CXXFLAGS = -std=gnu++0x` instead of `c++0x`.

But I still get the same call, and I don't know how to change the flag.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

I found the right CXXFLAGS to modify in the file "configure".

Now the call uses the right flag and the installation worked fine!

Comment: Consider writing a bug report so the author can change it in `configure.ac`.